# How to signal about 'retry exceeded' during concurrent write in Java through Exception?

Tags: java, exception, concurrency, containers, distributed-computing

I have Java class which has intention to support distributed container. During the 'change publication' there is always possibility of conflict so there is retry implemented. But there is always probability of number of re-tries exceeded.

Is there any 'standard' or recommended way to signal this situation in Java with exception? `java.io.IOException` (what I'm using now) looks like non-relevant as there is no actual IO error, it is just logic conflict around concurrency. Any grounded recommendation of something more specific?

Comment: What is wrong implementing your custom `Exception`/`RuntimeException` subclass?

Comment: You said it, the word 'custom'. :-) Acceptable but I'd like better solution if it is possible.

Comment: I doubt there is a standard way. I guess `java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException` might better express this condition than `IOException` does though. (I would go with a custom `RuntimeException` with a member how many retries were failed.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the application I'm working on we keep a `List` of the exceptions that have resulted in job retries, then when the job terminates we log (via [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/)) a serialized `JobSummary` object that includes the list of exceptions and their stack traces (gained via [ExceptionUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/exception/ExceptionUtils.html)) as well as whether the number of retries was exceeded (i.e. whether the job ultimately succeeded or failed).  Had we opted for throwing an exception instead of logging then we'd have had put the `JobSummary` data in a subclass of `RumTimeException` or `Exception` (as suggested by @Gábor Bakos in the comments).  In general, there's nothing wrong with rolling your own exception class(es) if doing so provides better debugging/logging/etc data.